# Is it possible to have paging enabled in real mode?

Tags: x86, paging, real-mode

Is it possible to have paging enabled in real mode, for example during BIOS execution. If it is enabled what is the use of having paging in real mode

Comment: Segment registers is the most similar you can get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121093/whats-the-type-of-memory-management-when-the-os-booted-paging-or-no-paging

Answer (score 4):

**No**, From [Intel Manual Vol 3A](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html) Chapter 2.5

> Paging (bit 31 of CR0) — Enables paging when set; disables paging when clear. When paging is
>   disabled, all linear addresses are treated as physical addresses. **The PG flag has no effect if the PE flag (bit
>   0 of register CR0) is not also set**; setting the PG flag when the PE flag is clear causes a general-protection
>   exception (#GP). See also: Chapter 4, “Paging.”

*(Emphasis mine)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and pointing out the reference as well, actually the reason I asked this question is in the following patent US 7568061 they mention the location of IVT, BDA and expansion ROM area as virtual space. " The page table (104) represents a map between a virtual memory address space and a physical address space", although the context of the discussion is BIOS which is running in real mode.

Comment: Here is the link for this patent
https://www.google.co.in/patents/US7568061?dq=prasenjit+roy&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rZWTVZX_IeS8mgXLvYnYAQ&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAA

Comment: @ArkaSharma that document seem to use a lot of personal terminology. Look at this sentence *The virtual memory address space is the range of computer memory addresses addressable by a computer processor. For example, a 16-bit processor has a virtual address space that extends from zero kilobytes (‘KB’) to 64 KB, while a 32-bit computer processor can have a virtual address space that extends from zero gigabytes (‘GB’) to 4 GB.* Not very correct. Anyway this seems a revival of the old Expansion Memory thing with a custom hardware MMU and, so it is independent from the CPU.